# Launching Web Browser from Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, process.start

Is it possible to launch a web browser from a windows service?  I have created a basic service in C# and installed it under the "LocalSystem" security profile.

The code for the service looks as follows:

```
namespace Bootloader
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            string target = "http://www.microsoft.com";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When the service runs, nothing happens.  The documentation on windows service say that they do not have any UI, but does that mean launching a web browser is not possible.

Comment: I am curious what you are trying to accomplish. Do you need your windows service to interact with the currently logged on user? If so, why is it a windows service? What happens when there is no user logged on? Why does a background service need to interact with a user? etc. ad inf.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Depending on the version of Windows you're running on, the browser window may, or may not, not appear. Having a service provide UI is a **bad thing** ... Google "shatter attack"

Comment: I'm working on a program that will run in the background listening on a port that will pop up an internet browser and other UI when it receives certain commands.  It sounds like an application with a hidden windows is the way to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible only in XP and lower.  In Vista, Windows Services run on a separate desktop completely.  You'll have to have something running in the user's desktop to accomplish this.

Write an app with a hidden window that starts at startup as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible. I know that if you want to run Watin (functional tests that run in a browser instance) cannot be run from my CI environment, if this is running as a service, but only if it runs as an app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be done, but you'll need to do extra work in order to deal with the process isolation model (window stations and desktops).  Take a look at this page: [Process Connection to a Window Station](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684859%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Since you can't modify the browser, you may need to write a shim that changes the context and then invokes the browser.

A workaround is to run your service as an interactive service, but this is deprecated and won't work in newer versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Services are explicitly forbidden from interacting with the user. Since Vista this is enforced, see [Interactive Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502(VS.85).aspx):

> **Important**  Services cannot directly
>   interact with a user as of Windows
>   Vista. Therefore, the techniques
>   mentioned in the section titled Using
>   an Interactive Service should not be
>   used in new code.

The solution is to separate the inteactive part into a normal process that is launched when the user session starts (ie. a Start-Up program). This process can then communicate with the service via its IPC of choice (shared memeory, net pipes, TCP etc). The service can direct this process to start programs when needed.