# Is there a way to bring an application's GUI to the current desktop?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-services

Background:
Started a fair amount of work before realizing that [a Windows Service cannot start an app with a GUI that displays without potential problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application).   The proper solution of separating the GUI of the app to be started is non-trivial, so I'm trying to think of alternative solutions.

There is a GUI to manage the service that is a separate executable, but the process to be launched (actually multiple instances of it) has its own GUI that needs to be shown. It doesn't need to be made visible by the service itself, but it needs to be at least able to be made visible by another process with a visible GUI.  The Windows User that is running the service and that needs to see the GUI of the launched process is the same and known at install time.

Is there some way to accomplish this or is it back to the drawing board?

Also both the service and the app to launch are both our code and modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to suggest that you look at the WTS* functions and CreateProcessAsUser and then I followed the link you provided and saw that you have already considered this and dismissed it.

As an alternative, if I understood you correctly you have a Windows Service and GUI which is used to manage the service. So why not use the communication channel you have between the Service and the management GUI to send a message from the service to the management GUI and have the management GUI launch the other GUI apps on behalf of the service? Of course this would assume that the management GUI is always running.

You might even do this with a hidden application that is not visible and launches when the user logs-in, that way you reduce the risk of the user inadvertantly closing the application, this would be a separate app from the actual management application.