# Displaying a UI from TFS Team Build

Tags: tfs

In my Team Build, I have to run an application that displays a UI. This application is configured to run without user input if we run it with the appropriate command line parameter.

When I attempt to run this locally, it runs without error, but if I run it from the Team Build, the User Interface never displays, and the process just hangs. I can only imagine that this is happening because the TFSBuildServiceHost service is running as a specific user. After doing a little bit of research, I found that services not running as the local service account could not display a User Interface.

With that in mind, I changed my Workflow to include an InvokeProcess activity invoking [PsExec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) and having that run my application with the -i and -s parameters. The idea behind this was that by adding the -s parameter, it would be able to actually display a User Interface. Sadly this did not work. If I add the -h parameter (Runs the executable with its elevated token) I get a strange popup from Interactive Service Detection asking me if I would like to show a message that is trying to be sent.

Is there a way to always accept a message that is being sent?
Does anyone know how to run an application that displays a UI from a Team Build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure your build service to run in interactive mode. Open the TFS administration console, select Build Configuration, click Properties on your BuildService and select Run build service as: Interactive Process. Of course, you'll need to remain logged onto that machine for the duration.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you sir.

I ended up adding a new value in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run directory that pointed to the build service's executable. ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\TFSBuildServiceHost.exe" in my case)

This enabled an automatic log on so I wouldn't have to repeatedly enter my password anytime someone logged on the build agent.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this thread: [How can a Windows service execute a GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application) 
In short you need to enumerate the active sessions using [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), find the console session and [create the process as that user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).