# Access to GUI on remote machine using PowerShell and WinRM

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-desktop, ui-automation

Is it possible to get access to a GUI on a remote machine using PowerShell with for example WinRM?

I have an application which uses UI Automation framework to examine some GUI.
This application should be run remotely on some machine.

Right now I am able to run application remotely but I can't see any UI elements (which is quite obvious).

What's the best approach for this.

Comment: Use https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH instead of WinRM. Run sshd on the desktop.
Without running the host process on the desktop the only real option is http://rzander.azurewebsites.net/create-a-process-as-loggedon-user/.
I don't know about any existing tools that use that kind of spawn, none of the built-in powershell, winrm, cim, psexec forms will do this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand begining in Vista Microsoft block acces to the interactive desktop from a service. To make working on Seven, my services which were interacting with the user desktop in XP, I create a process working on the user Desktop that relay the service interaction. [How can a Windows service execute a GUI application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267866/608772) explain some other solution, but I'am not sure that they are working on Seven/2008R2.

PS : according to [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347642.aspx) Some native Windows programs, such as programs with a user interface, console applications that prompt for input, and console applications that use the Win32 console API, do not work correctly in the Windows PowerShell remote host.