# PowerShell Send Popup Message to users in group

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have this PS code:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('system.windows.forms'); [system.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::show('Reminder: Updates)
```

Wondering if its possible to send this to remote users, particularly ones in a specific AD group.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could create a script that runs when a user logs in, a server. Then you just send the server a command and then that script displays the popup message.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand.

You can execute the script on a remote computer, **but the user will not see the popup**. This is because the remote process is not allowed to interact with the user Desktop.

PS : have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345901/608772)

I think that on XP you can use `NET SEND` in upper versions you have `MSG.EXE` or third party [WinSent](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/).

Comment: Hi JPBlanc do you know of any way do send notification via PowerShell to the user? Thanks for your input bud.

Comment: I improve my answer for that.