# Launching a GUI application from Windows service

Tags: windows, winapi, service, createprocess, launching-application

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application) and I had little success with the given answer. It said to

> use WTSEnumerateSessions to find the right desktop

but all I got was the station name in the `WTS_SESSION_INFO` struct. The names I saw (e.g. "console", "service") were nothing like the station/desktop names like "Winsta0\default". The answer proceed to state

> then CreateProcessAsUser to start the application on that desktop (you pass it the handle of the desktop as part of the STARTUPINFO structure)

I don't think it's referring to a `HANDLE` variable for the desktop since `STARTUPINFO` has no members for that. What I think it's referring to is the `lpDesktop` member which allows you to specify the station/desktop name. Using names returned by `WTSEnumerateSessions` failed to launch any visible UI, whereas "Winsta0\default" did.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried WTSEnumerateSessions on Windows Seven: my user session (session 1) is named "Console".

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.