# Launch Windows Application from Webservice

Tags: vb.net, web-services

Let me start out by saying I know this is highly not recommended, but for the sake of figuring something out, I'm wanting to launch Notepad via a Webservice...

```
        Dim p As New Process
        Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo
        Dim fullPath As String = "C:\windows\notepad.exe"
        pi.FileName = fullPath
        pi.CreateNoWindow = False
        pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
        p.StartInfo = pi
        p.Start()
```

This code executes without issue and it does in fact launch Notepad as I can see it running in Task Manager, however there is no window for Notepad displayed.  How do I go about making the window visible when I launch it?

Comment: maybe it's running for another user's account?

Comment: Ooh, didn't even think about that.  Let me check and see.

Comment: Ok, so I have confirmed that it is now running the application as the current logged in user however, there is still no window.

Comment: Looks like it's not very simple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Looks like I'm going to need to look at "CreateProcessAsUser".  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please close this question if you have an answer

Comment: I use Process.Start with no problem. E.G. Process.Start("IExplore", "http://www.somewebsite.com") launches an internet explorer window with the given website as a parameter. not from a webservice though. I assume process.start is just a shorthand way of doing what you have done in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following script  this can be used to run the `notepad` application from the web by calling the function `openApplication()`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function openApplication()
    {
        var winShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        var prog = "c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe";
        winShell.Run('"'+prog+'"',1);
    }
</script>
```