# Windows 8 Execute .exe From Service Without User?

Tags: c#, service, windows-8, process

I've read some extensive discussion from here:

[How can a Windows service execute a GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application)

And have some understanding that for a service to launch an .exe they need user credentials.
The exe I need to have running is a command line application that has no output, but does not require a specific user to run.

Is there a way to allow my service to run the command line application so I don't have to put in user credentials?

I tried using Process.Start with process info CreateNoWindow set to true and UseShellExecute set to false, but still the command line program will not execute.

Comment: You can't open up a GUI from a service. Is the command a built-in command in Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately, the command isn't a windows command. It's located in Program Files. But the program isn't a gui, it's a command line executable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Windows service wrapper](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw), specifically:

[StartProcess in Main.cs](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/blob/master/Main.cs#L390)