# How to make a Windows service interactive

Tags: c#, windows, service

On the https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms683502 page (v=vs.85) of .aspx/ it is written as to make that the service worked in an interactive mode. There it is written that it is necessary to cause the CreateService function. I not absolutely understand where it needs to be done. I use C# Visual Studio 2013 for creation of service from the Windows Service template, but there didn't find anywhere to execute required in article Microsoft. I ask prompt. Very much it is necessary to create interactive service on C#. I will be glad to any help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What sort of interaction are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237283/1769485) has already been asked although unfortunately it might not be the answer you like.

In summary interactive services are frowned upon due to security risks and is not supported since Windows Vista. Although there is a documented workaround presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application) which applies to C++ code where service is created using the WinAPI call of **CreateProcessAsUser**.

Other than the above, if you elaborate your problem a bit more we could provide alternative solutions.

Comment: No worries, updated the answer :), appreciate if you remove the -1

Comment: Hopefully that's better? :)